# how to get deep relation from polymorphic pivot table and 2 targets

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a pivot table named "taggables"
it contains a tag_id, a taggable_id and taggable_type.

The taggable_type contains one of 2 values (socialaccount or benchmark)

The problem is simple :
A benchmark have tags and the social_account have also tags.

I want to find all the accounts having the same tags of one or more benchmarks

After a little struggle I came up with this query

```
SELECT *, 
       taggable_id                          AS social_account_id, 
       Group_concat(tag_id ORDER BY tag_id) AS tags 
FROM   `taggables` 
WHERE  taggable_type = "app\\socialaccount" 
GROUP  BY ( social_account_id ) 
HAVING tags IN (SELECT Group_concat(tag_id ORDER BY tag_id) AS tags 
                FROM   `taggables` 
                WHERE  taggable_type = "app\\benchmark" 
                       AND taggable_id IN ( 1, 2 ) 
                GROUP  BY ( taggable_id ))
```

The above query gives correct number of rows from the query but nothing shows up in phpMyAdmin

If I add a LIMIT 1 to the query, it does return one of the results.

Comment: A really good tip is NEVER USE `SELECT *`. (With dull caveats) Your GROUP BY clause must include all non-aggregated columns in the SELECT. Address those issues, and we can begin to help.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *,taggable_id as social_account_id, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id ORdeR by tag_id) as tags FROM `taggables` 
WHERE taggable_type LIKE '%SocialAccount%'
GROUP BY (social_account_id) 
HAVING tags IN ( 
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id ORdeR by tag_id) as tags FROM `taggables` 
    WHERE taggable_type LIKE '%Benchmark%' AND taggable_id IN (1,2) 
    GROUP BY (taggable_id)
 )
```